# Postgres reltuples seems to return twice the number of values

Tags: postgres-9.6

I am using this query to get approx row count.

`SELECT reltuples AS approximate_row_count FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'table_name';`

This was recommended by this article to get fast approx row counts: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate

But sometimes it seems to give twice the number of rows. This is happening only after upgrading to `9.6.8`. It used to work right all the time.

The problem seems to fix itself when I run `ANALYZE table_name`. After sometime, the problem returns.

I am not exactly sure why this is happening. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: **double** does not sound like reproducible problem. `pg_stat` show estimations, based on gathered info while analyzing. it's not promised to be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

My guess right now is that this is to do with a bug with Analyze vacuum functionality in Postgres 9.8.6 after writing to the postgres mailing list. Expected to be fixed in the next minor update of Postgres.

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFWmNu8SfSgBWcMCaWJfDLbcFUN3riC9jDuzOd08QsJgAqv%2B4A%40mail.gmail.com
3.